# Why is printing this circular queue leading to an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, queue

I'm trying to implement a static circular queue using C++ in Visual Studio 2019 and facing some problems.

## Printing a circular queue (Semantic Error)

I have overloaded the operator `<<` so that I can use the `Queue` object with `cout`. I want the queue to start displaying elements from the `q[front]` all the way till `Q[rear]`. I have to check if `front == rear` as the terminating condition since I have to start printing from the front and go all the way till rear. Since, just that can't distinguish between an overflow and underflow, I have added additional variables `rLap` and `fLap` that keep track of how many times `front` and `rear` have traversed. If rLap is greater, rear approached front which means it is an overflow and if `fLap == rLap` then vice-versa

The problem is if I just keep enqueueing till an overflow, and try to print using `cout << Q;`, the program enters an infinite loop. Where am I going wrong?
Also, is there a more elegant way to do this?

I'm quite a beginner in C++ so please let me know if I'm doing something incorrectly or inefficiently.

Thanks in Advance.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "menu.h"
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
class Queue {
    int front, rear, size, fLap, rLap;
    int* Q;

public:
        Queue(int);
        void enqueue(int);
        int dequeue(); 
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, Queue);
};
Queue::Queue(int size_) : size(size_), rear(0), front(0), fLap(0), rLap(0)
{
    try { Q = new int[size]; }
    catch (bad_alloc e) { cout << "Bad value for size"; exit(0) } //Why is new not throwing bad_alloc for negative values?
}

void Queue::enqueue(int elem)
{
    try { if (front == rear && rLap > fLap) throw overflow_error("Queue is full."); }
    catch (overflow_error e) { cerr << e.what(); _getch();  return; }
    Q[rear] = elem;
    rear++;
    if (rear == size) {
        rear = 0; 
        rLap++;
    }
}
int Queue::dequeue()
{

    try { if (front == rear && rLap == fLap)  throw underflow_error("Queue is empty."); } //front follows rear so fLap can never be greater than rLap
    catch (underflow_error e) { cerr << e.what(); return {}; } //How to return error?
    int elem = Q[front];
    front++;
    if (front == size) {
        front = 0;
        fLap++;
    }
    return elem;
}


ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Queue q)
{
    out << '\n';
    if (q.front == q.rear && q.fLap == q.rLap)/*underflow*/ { out << "Queue is empty"; return out; }
    int i = q.front;
    if (q.front == q.rear && q.rLap > q.fLap)/*overflow*/ { out << q.Q[i] << '\t'; i++; }
    for (; i != q.rear ; i++)
    {
        if (i == q.size) i = 0; 
        out << q.Q[i] << "\t";

    }
    return out;
}
int main()
{
    Queue Q(0);
    cout << "\nCreate a new Queue? (Y/N)";
    char yn;
    cin >> yn;
    if (yn == 'Y' || yn == 'y')
    {
        cout << "\nEnter Queue Size >>>";
        int size;
        cin >> size;
        Q = Queue(size); 
        cout << "\nQueue created";
        _getch();
    }
    else exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    do {
        system("CLS");
                cout << "\nEnter:"
        cout << "\n1 to Enquque";
                cout << "\n2 to Dequeue";
                cout << "\n3 to Peek";
                cout << "\n Or enter any other choice to exit>>>"

        int opt;
        cin >> opt;
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            cout << "\nEnter element to enqueue >>>";
            int el;
            cin >> el;
            Q.enqueue(el);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            cout << "\n Element dequeued is :" << Q.dequeue();
            _getch();
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            cout << Q;
            _getch();
            break;
        }
        default:
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    } while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The shown queue algorithm is fundamentally flawed. A queue proper requires exactly three values: size, the front, and the rear. Not five values. It is unclear what those two extra values are supposed to be doing, but whatever they're doing, it's wrong, because they should not exist at all. The infinite loop is just the manifestation of the design flaw. Additionally, the shown Queue class violates the Rule Of Three, but because its memory management is not fully complete, this does not manifest itself. As soon as an attempt is made to free its memory, crashes galore...

Comment: The keyword for your case is "debugger". Use it to trace your loop by each iteration and observe how variables are changed.

Comment: My `rear` points to the next free location not the last element.

Comment: Just because there are extra variables doesn't mean the entire algorithm is "fundamentally flawed". There is more than one way to skin any cat; perhaps they're used in a superfluous fashion, or perhaps they're key to an algorithm that doesn't look like the one you're used to but regardless gets the job done. Though at first glance that is possibly not the case here. Which resource are you using to learn queues, Amal?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you :) It is part of my course, also I have read about them from sites like Wikipedia to gain an understanding of how they work. I have not looked at other algorithms that implement circular queue, this was a trial to do it my way. The program seems to be working fine for all other cases except for if you only keep enqueueing without dequeueing and print once it's full, it leads to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i == q.size) i = 0;
```

will fail if `q.rear` is at zero as you "jump over" in the for-loop. That may one of the flaws you are looking for.